# How does Manpower affect my nation?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

How does manpower affect my nation? I have a rough understanding of Manpower but I don't fully grasp how Manpower affects game-play. What causes it to decrease? Is it just troop deaths? What are the effects of a low manpower?

I know that each province has a manpower rating that dictates how much manpower it puts towards the nation each month, and I know this can be improved by ideas and buildings. 
I know that your max manpower is 10 times the base contribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manpower is a crucial factor in creating and maintaining larger armies.

From the ingame help text:

> Manpower represents how many able men of military age your nation has available.
>
> Manpower is used to recruit new troops and to reinforce armies that have suffered casualties in war.

---

Whenever you want to recruit a new troop, you have to "pay" 1,000 manpower. If you don't have enough manpower, you cannot raise new troops.

When your troops lose men in fights or because of attrition, they will automatically be restocked from your manpower pool. If you don't have enough manpower available, replenishing your troops will happen a lot slower. (capped by the speed with which your manpower regenerates)

The exception to this are mercenaries, which do not drain manpower when being built or replenished. Low manpower is one of the main reasons why you would want to recruit mercenaries.

To sum it up: **Manpower can be a deciding factor in war.** You will find that if you are taking heavy losses during war you will not be able to replenish your troops fast enough or raise new troops because of low manpower. This might give your opponent the necessary edge to conquer your lands.

You can find more info about the topic in the [EU4 wiki entry on manpower](http://eu4wiki.com/Manpower).

Comment: Ahh so manpower is the reserve pool to pull troops from, that makes sense, thankyou

Comment: I'd make the mistake of constantly assaulting provinces I'm seiging in a drawn out war. I'd run out of mainpower for my reserves and eventually get rolled.

Answer (score 0):

Having manpower value that's less then 25% of max may trigger the [Peasant War](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Peasants%27_war_events) event which can be brutal if your manpower is low because of war. This will trigger peasant revolts all over your country, with stacks in the 10-20 regiment range. I've also seen a province under siege because of one peasant revolt trigger another revolt, thus having a stack of 20-30. Not fun.